# what is the default cubic spline type when using scipy.interpolate.interp1d?

Tags: python, scipy, spline

There are various cubic splines if we specifying different constraints, like Natural Cubic Spline, Hermite Cubic Spline and Financial cubic spline.

I'm wondering what's default cubic spline method when we use scipy.interpolate.interp1d and set `kind=cubic`?

And What's the boundary constraints for 'kind=quardratic' ?

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


def f(x):
    return np.exp(np.sin(-x))

a=np.linspace(-6,3,100)
b=f(a)

x = np.linspace(-6, 3, 5)
y = f(x)

splineFunc= interp1d(x=x, y=y, kind='cubic')

plt.plot(a,b)
plt.plot(a, splineFunc(a))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: It's not-a-knot by default.

`interp1d(..., kind='cubic')` delegates to `make_interp_spline`, which allows explicit control over the boundary conditions via the `bc_type` parameter.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html

By the way, I'd recommend to use `make_interp_spline` directly instead of going through interp1d.